# Webservice method that receives two values/fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, api

Ok, so here is my issue:
I am creating a Windows 8 store app in javascript, that gets its data from an API written in C# with asp. The store has been using several methods that require two fields (exemple: sending an employee id and a record Id to verify if the record belongs to the employee and return more details). However, for some reason I have a method that simply refuses to work. Here is the method in the controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("teste")]
    public IEnumerable<EmployeeProjectViewModel> teste(int iUserMasterId, int iEmployeeOrganizationsId)
    {
        var Query = from eprojects in db.EmployeeProjects
                    where eprojects.UserMasterId == iUserMasterId
                    && eprojects.Deleted == false
                    && eprojects.EmployeeOrganizationsId == iEmployeeOrganizationsId
                    select new EmployeeProjectViewModel
                    {
                        EmployeeProjectsId = eprojects.EmployeeProjectsId,
                        UserMasterId = eprojects.UserMasterId,
                        Name = eprojects.ProjectName,
                        Month = eprojects.ProjectMonth,
                        Year = eprojects.ProjectYear,
                        URL = eprojects.ProjectURL,
                        Description = eprojects.ProjectDescription,
                    };
        return Query;
    }
```

And the routeConfig code:

```
                routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "teste",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/teste/{iUserMasterId}/{iEmployeeOrganizationsId}",
defaults: new
{
    action = "teste"
});
```

The error it gives me is 404: Method not found in controller (verified with Fiddler). The controller is correct however because there are more methods in the controller. I have also noticed that other methods in the same controller that also use more than one field end up failing too.
What am I doing wrong? I've compared both of these codes with other controllers I have that also work with multiple fields and they all seem to be working fine.

EDIT:
Here's the request sample:

```
    {"$id":"1","Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:55105/api/EmployeeProjects/teste/8/2'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'EmployeeProjects' that matches the request."}
```

Comment: looks like your routing is a little weird. You should include the WHOLE of the routeConfig code, since order matters. However I suspect that the issue is that the route you added isn't being called at all (since your default is before the "teste" route and your request pattern matched that).

Comment: My default is after the "teste" route*. I tried changing orders and it didn't work anyway. I won't be adding all the routeconfig code, it's really big, and you really don't need all of it. If there's something you need in particular just ask.

Comment: Also, even in failure, it enters the controller, it just can't find the method.

Comment: Could you post a sample request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved. Apparently some of our previous colleagues had written some routes in the routeconfig that were incomplete, thus stopping every route beneath them from being recognized.